# R trouble encoding windows

Tags: r

I wasted a lot of time for reading about R encoding hell, but unfortunately didnt find decision.

I need in R to assign character var with "ñ" symbol

```
utm <- "españa"
```

And after this pass this var as argument to google api function

```
pvs <- google_analytics_4(id, 
                          date_range = c(date - 7, date - 1), 
                          metrics = "pageviews",
                          dimensions = "countryIsoCode",
                          dim_filters = filter_clause_ga4(list(dim_filter("source", "EXACT", utm))))
```

But R/R Studio/Windows (I dont know what) read "españa" as "espana" and pass it to google_analytics_4() argument and as result GoogleAPI dont return any data, because "espana" utm-tag doesnt use.
I read about set Sys.getlocale and Sys.setlocale and anothers things, but dont find how fix it.

So what is the easiest way to pass exactly "españa" rather "espana".

P.S.

```
> sessionInfo()
```

R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251  LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251    LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251 LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0 tools_3.4.0

Comment: Please provide your `sessionInfo()` here to understand your current settings. And what does `utm` print on the console (in my case: `[1] "españa"` - as expected). Please help us to understand your problem by posting a self-contained example so that we can reproduce you problem (e. g. I do not know the functions `filter_clause_ga4()` and `dim_filter()` where the source of your problem could be hidden)...

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted your session info, the best suggestion I can give is that you use `charToRaw("ñ")`. This will return a code, something like `c3 b1`. It's usually the second one you use, along with `\u00`.

For example, on my Mac, getting the character `Ã`, I can use something like:

```
> print("\u00c3")
[1] "Ã"
```

You can assign this code as part of `utm`:

```
utm <- "espa\u00b1a`.
```

Keep in mind this works on *my* computer, with *my* settings. As R Yoda mentioned in the comments, you'll need to check on your own machine.